# external hard drive not showing with fdisk & lsblk

Tags: usb, hard-disk, fdisk, dmesg, lsblk

this is output of `dmesg`

```
[   17.064706] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   22.496752] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   22.600534] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   27.616658] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   27.742801] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[   28.163823] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   33.248666] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   33.352651] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   38.368663] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   38.671823] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   44.000689] usb 2-2: unable to get BOS descriptor
[   49.120774] usb 2-2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[   49.121145] usb 2-2: can't read configurations, error -110
[   49.143813] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device


[  748.588806] [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* PPS state mismatch
[ 1628.368022] [drm:wait_panel_status [i915]] *ERROR* PPS state mismatch
(deleted repeated error message)
[ 1762.194218] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1762.397556] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=1561
[ 1762.397574] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1762.397646] usb 1-2: Product: ACASIS
[ 1762.397658] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: ACASIS
[ 1762.397668] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: DB9876543213C
[ 1762.409906] scsi host1: uas
[ 1762.411085] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ACASIS                    0204 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1791.096578] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=174191 end=174192) time 297 us, min 763, max 767, scanline start 759, end 773
```

this is some of the error.

I tried to run `fdisk -l` & `lsblk`

the external hard drive is not detected but i noted that `dmesg` sees it. How to solve the problem?

Comment: What kind of external drive is it? USB? For it looks as if it is begin disconnected about 30 seconds after being detected. Have you checked the cable/connectors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to restore data, usb drive not properly detected?](https://superuser.com/a/719336)

Comment: I am using a hard disk drive, which gets power from the computer. using a cable to link up the drive and computer. the drive shows it running, but it's not detected.

Answer (score 1):

use cable with external power source

[image: y cable]

Comment: only has one input port. which links to the computer.

Comment: current from usb is limited. buy another cable